# Error occurring during bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, therubyracer

Running bundle update in terminal inside of my project folder and an error occurs and Bundler can't continue. How can I resolve this and run a successful bundle update?

Mac osx

Terminal output:

```
master*$ bundle update
Fetching source index from http://code.thesite.com/
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.2) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activesupport (4.0.1) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.1) 
Using mime-types (1.25) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.1) 
Using activemodel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord (4.0.1) 
Using rails-observers (0.1.2) 
Using activeresource (4.0.0) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using airbrake (3.1.14) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using highline (1.6.20) 
Using net-ssh (2.7.0) 
Using net-scp (1.1.2) 
Using net-sftp (2.1.2) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0) 
Using capistrano (2.15.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.1) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1) 
Using rvm-capistrano (1.5.1) 
Using cogo_deploy (1.0.5) 
Using geoip-c (0.9.1) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using haml (4.0.4) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Using mini_portile (0.5.2) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.11) 
Using net-http-persistent (2.9) 
Using nokogiri (1.6.0) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1) 
Using rails (4.0.1) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using sanitize (2.0.6) 
Using sass (3.2.12) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.1) 
Using sdoc (0.3.20) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8) 
Installing therubyracer (0.10.2) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling rr.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
rr.cpp:48:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_array.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_callbacks.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_context.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_date.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_debug.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_exception.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_exception.cpp:10:16: warning: unused variable 'stack' [-Wunused-variable]
  static void* stack[20];
               ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_external.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_external.cpp:10:9: warning: unused variable 'references' [-Wunused-variable]
  VALUE references;
        ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_function.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_handle.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_locker.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_locker.cpp:45:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
v8_locker.cpp:85:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
    }
    ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling v8_message.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_object.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_object.cpp:77:19: warning: unused variable 'proto' [-Wunused-variable]
    Handle<Value> proto(rr_rb2v8(prototype));
                  ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_script.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_string.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_template.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_try_catch.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_v8.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
compiling v8_value.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
v8_value.cpp:100:9: warning: unused function 'ToInt32' [-Wunused-function]
  VALUE ToInt32(VALUE self) {
        ^
1 warning generated.
compiling v8_weakref.cpp
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-rdynamic'
linking shared-object v8.bundle
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/darcy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/libv8-3.3.10.4/lib/libv8/build/v8/libv8.a'
make: *** [v8.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.10.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.10.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Code in my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems:gems@code.thesite.com'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

gem 'wildcat', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'business_deploy', '~> 1.0.0', :require => false

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

In Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.1)
      activemodel (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    arel (4.0.1)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    builder (3.1.4)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    jbuilder (1.5.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activerecord (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.1)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    railties (4.0.1)
      actionpack (= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (= 4.0.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.2.12)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    sprockets (2.10.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.8)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.3.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.3.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 4.0.1)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  sdoc
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install libv8 (gem install libv8), then installing therubyracer. You will need to have Apple XCode installed first (install from the App Store) as this includes the c compiler that you will need to build libv8.

EDIT: Once you have installed XCode, if you are using the latest version you will need to manually install the "command line tools" to get the c compiler, you can find this in XCode --> preferences --> downloads --> install command line tools.
Hope this helps you....

```
brew install apple-gcc42

gem install libv8

gem install therubyracer
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install the latest Xcode and select the Command Line Tools during install.